# Changing a particular value of a particular key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, machine-learning, data-science

I am new to Data Science .I am Having Problem in changing a particaular key's particular value in dictionary.I have a dictionary which represents class of iris plant each have 4 attributes sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length and petal_width
For e.g

**iris-setosa={sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width}**

**iris-veriginica={sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width}**

**iris-veronica={sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width}**

Initially i have initialized all these attributes to zero.
Now i want just to change sepal_length of iris-setosa to 2 by adding 2 in it(it is mandatory to do it by addition only)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dic={}
dic2={}


dic['sepal_length']=0
dic['petal_length']=0
dic['sepal_width']=0
dic['petal_width']=0
dic2['iris-setosa']=dic
dic2['iris-verginica']=dic
dic2['iris-veronica']=dic


dic2['iris-setosa']['sepal_length']=dic2['iris-setosa']['sepal_length']+2
print(dic2)
```

**but the result come out is as :**

```
{'iris-setosa': {'sepal_width': 0, 'petal_width': 0, 'sepal_length': 2, 'petal_length': 0}, 'iris-verginica': {'sepal_width': 0, 'petal_width': 0, 'sepal_length': 2, 'petal_length': 0}, 'iris-veronica': {'sepal_width': 0, 'petal_width': 0, 'sepal_length': 2, 'petal_length': 0}}
```

the above code is updating sepal_length of all i.e iris-setosa,iris-verginica and iris-veronica,Which was not required.How should i change value of sepal_length of iris-setosa only. Please ignore any grammatical mistake if i made any.

Answer (score 1):

All three entries in `dic2` point to **the same dictionary**. So when you update it via one reference, all entries will change (since they are in fact the same dictionary). Instead, you should create a separate dictionary for each entry, e.g.:

```py
dic={}

for name in ['iris-setosa', 'iris-verginica', 'iris-veronica']:
    entry = {'sepal_length' : 0, 'petal_length' : 0, 'sepal_width' : 0, 'petal_width' : 0}
    dic[name] = entry

dic['iris-setosa']['sepal_length'] = dic['iris-setosa']['sepal_length'] + 2
```